# Entity Framework to search a lot of records in SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a database (Microsoft SQL Server 2014) and our software is written in C#. We put a lot of PDF files in the database as a link to the actual path.

When we create the record that holds the path, I also read all the text from the PDF and split all the text into chunks of 50 digits.

If some of the clients search for a word in the PDF, we query for it with entity framework in our SQL  database.

We search like this:

```
dc.DBDCDocumentIndex.Include("DBDCDocument")
                    .Where(p => p.DBDCDocument.latestrevision 
                                && p.DBProjectID == p.DBProjectID 
                                &&  p.Index.IndexOf(searchword) != -1)
                    .ToList();
```

Is this a good way of doing this?

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **concrete** database system (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: i have updated the question.

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework against anything but MSSQL you're bringing yourself extra pain, so unless you explicitly state you're not it's a fair assumption that's the engine you're running on.

Comment: A few pieces of advice: 1. Arbitrarily splitting things into pieces may not make sense; unless the files are enormous you might as well put the full text into SQL in one BLOB field. 2. if you're doing full-text searching, you might want to look into full text indexing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql 3. I'd try doing it this way first, so it might be an acceptable approach to the problem.

Comment: Regardless, 50 characters is a weird place to split them.  I'd go with varchar(max) myself if I were to try this as a performance enhancement.